# Game freezes at load screen after latest patch

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

It appears that after I patched Black Ops II, the load screen won't show up.  Instead, my Xbox freezes when I try to start the game, and I'm forced to turn the power off and turn it back on (or manually eject the disc) for regular function (without use of the game).

Is there any fix for this?

For the record, I've attempted to resolve the issue by:

- Deleting the system cache.
- Deleting the update.
- Reinstalling the update.

You should also note that:

- I've set Black Ops so that it starts straight into Xbox Live.
- I never took the game disc out of the Xbox, nor was the system moved at any point -- there were no physical disruptions involved whatsoever.

Are there any other options?

Comment: We are having the same problem. Load screen appears and then the screen goes black. Have you figured anything out?

Comment: Not at all.  I'm really going out of my mind.  Vacation's wasting away and today's Christmas, so the Activision call center is AWOL.  Horrendous.  I don't even get a splash screen -- just a black screen once I press "Play COD: Black Ops II" in the Xbox home.

Comment: Mine is freezing when its loading to play the match. A green screen pops up instead of the map image.

Comment: did you ever find a fix for this? I have the problem of it freezing when it's about to go into a game on League Play, but then I have to eject the disk and restart it. It only happens every so often.

Comment: I replaced the game at Toys R' Us.  The software-related issue was never really solved.

Comment: Have you tried booting the game without being connected to xbox live. "When I try to start a game" as in the menus load and it is only when you go to matchmaking?

Comment: Try pressing the Xbox button till it freezes, then disconnect the controller and reconnect it. If it shows up on the front of the Xbox it may still be loading.

Comment: Have you tried installing the game to the Xbox? Also do you own DLC and was it originally downloaded to that Xbox? Are you using plug & play, intercooler, or extra USB devices? Finally, while it's unplugged completely at both ends; vaccuum the brick.

Answer (score -3):

The same thing happened to me. This is what you need to do:

1. Go on to another XBox
2. Make it so the loading screen is multiplayer

Comment: I already described that I did that.